# htaccess RewriteRule скрипт бана

Tags: .htaccess, ip

Вообщем есть скрипт бана, который делает свое дело после переадресации на него с .htaccess

Код в htaccess

Вот этот код работает:

```
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 123.123.123.123[NC] //Кроме этого ip посылать всех в ban.php
 RewriteRule admin/login ban.php [NC] //Строка отправляет в ban.php при совпадении запроса
```

А вот этот банит меня :(

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 123.123.123.123[OR] //Кроме этого ip посылать всех в ban.php
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 111.111.1. //И кроме ip с этой маской (если у меня динамич. ip
RewriteRule admin/login ban.php [NC] //Строка отправляет в ban.php при совпадении запроса
```

Как правильно добавить динамический IP?

Comment: Что-то из ваших комментариев к условиям не понятно: то ли эти ip надо переадресовать на ban.php, то ли все остальные.

Comment: Указанные ip - это исключения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз исключения, значит нужно использовать отрицание в условиях и ни каких [OR], так как ip не должен попадать ни в тот, ни в другой промежутки/адреса.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.1\.
RewriteRule admin/login ban.php [L]
```