# Условия htaccses

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите как создать в htaccses диррективу для переадресации с условием определения по ip

Пример:

```
если ip=2.2.2.2 или 3.3.3.3
то 301 редирект на site.ru
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^2\.2\.2\.2$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^3\.3\.3\.3$
RewriteRule .* http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

**UPD** Онлайн калькуляторы говорят, что для 86.102.72.240/28 ->

```
Хост(min):  86.102.72.241
Хост(max):  86.102.72.254
```

тогда можно весь диапазон записать одной регуляркой и правило будет таким:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.org
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^86\.102\.72\.2(4[1-9]|5[0-4])$
RewriteRule .* http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ага спасибо тогда еще один вопрос, даже два)

следуя логике тогда при условии в RewriteCond  будет что то вроде 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.org [AND] 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^2\.2\.2\.2$
RewriteRule .* http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]

 ?


и как поступать есть пул ip достаточно большой чтобы не прописывать каждый по отдельности?

Comment: @BroouzerKing, из первого ни чего не понял, из второго - можно указывать не точные ip, а подсети в виде `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^3\.3\.3\.`, `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^3\.3\.`. Или не нагружать .htaccess правилами, а перенести всю логику из него в роутер http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite

Comment: по первому пункту, уже есть условие редиректа аля 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.org как к этому условию добавить текущие.
по второму. вечер туплю, надо было сразу написать, что у меня пул этих самых подсетей например 86.102.72.240/28 и такого добра много

Comment: За ссылку спасибо, прочел, но в даннмо случае это не прокатит. это если можно так выразиться перевлочный домен. он пуст внем нет цмс и вообще ничего кроме файла htaccess, я коненчо могу накатать пхп файл с такой же маршрутизацией, но всетаки хотелось бы именно в htaccess . в данном случае "прибить гвозьдями " как метко выразились в том вопросе

Comment: @BroouzerKing, обновил ответ.

Comment: ага спасибо большое, а для полноты понимания, если не равно какому либо ip как прописать?

Comment: @BroouzerKing, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460859/htaccess-rewriterule-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0/460867#460867