# Как можно определенный ip отправить на другой сайт в htaccess?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, .htaccess

Как можно определенный ip отправить на другой сайт в htaccess ? Я не давно писал про спам на моем сайте. Так вот хочу чтобы этот гад с определенного ip редиректом переходил на другой домен и там ему говорилось гад и так далее и еще другие опознавательные данные о нем собрать. Ну достали уже 8 диапазон блокирую ip адресов Trusov Ilya Igorevych на него все оформлено. Причем вопрос спорный выходит, они видимо арендуют адреса а принадлежат они другим. Ну это уже другая история. Помогите ? Простите не много добавлю к вопросу а как можно редиректить диапазонами а то слишком большая у него сеть ? Редиректить диапазонами с применением cidr ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Условия htaccses](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552339/%d0%a3%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-htaccses)

Answer (score 0):

Через php

```
<?php
            $ip = '94.19.203.72'; // ip - заменить на вашего отправителя 
            if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $ip){
                header('Location: http://www.okolo.me/');
            exit;
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное господа Еще такой вопрос а как добавить скажем диапазон IP или несколько диапазонов? Можно CIDR использовать но как в код Htaccess это вставить ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (xxx.yyy.zzz.www|yyy.xxx.zzz.rrr|vvv.zzz.yyy.xxx)
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```